# How to avoid a memory leak when Python objects are passed to C using callbacks?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, callback, ctypes

To avoid a memory leak in the sutuation described below,  I would like to call Py_DecRef directly from Python.  Is there a way to do this?  Is there a better solution for this problem?

I am using ctypes to interface my Python code to a C library for which I do not have the code. The C library was not written for Python, so it doesn't know anything about Python objects.

The C library uses two callbacks: the first creates an object and returns a void* pointer to it,  and the second gets the pointer as parameter and is supposed to destroy it. In the C header files, the types of these callback functions are defined as follows:

```
typedef void* (*CreateCallback)();
typedef void (*DestroyCallback)(void*);
```

These callbacks could be defined in Python as shown below (simplified code). The current code has a memory leak as explained in the comments.

```
import ctypes

CreateCallback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)
DestroyCallback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.py_object)

class Object:
   pass # In the real application, this contains more code

@CreateCallback
def create():
   return Object()
   # Ctypes correctly increments the reference count of the 
   # object, to make sure it does not get garbage collected
   # while the C code holds a reference to it.

@DestroyCallback
def destroy(object):
   pass
   # Above, the reference count of the object should be
   # decremented, because the C code no longer holds a
   # reference to it. However, Ctypes does not know this so 
   # cannot do it automatically. How can I do this from
   # Python? Is it possible to call Py_DecRef or similar
   # directly from Python?
```

One option would be to create a C function that call Py_DecRef, compile that C function into a dll (or so for Linux), and call that from the destroy function above. That solution has at least two disadvantages:

1. It seems overly complex to create a dll just for one function
2. The C code would have to be compiled against a specific version of Python, instead of using whatever version of Python is running my Python code. Note that I need this to work on Windows, where a dll cannot contain undefined globals.

Comment: Have you tried `import gc; gc.collect()` after the object is destroyed to force Python to clear references?

Comment: If the C library has no knowledge of Python, what good is passing a Python object to it? Maybe you need to pass a `ctypes.Structure` instead?

Comment: @101 Yes I tried gc.collect (adding a __del__ method to Object, with a print statement) and the object does not get garbage collected.  I also added some C code (on Linux,  where it is easy to do for me) to check the actual reference count.  The create callback increments the reference count (which makes sense because it sends a reference to C code where Python cannot observe it anymore). The destroy callback does not decrement the reference count (which also makes sense in general,  because Python/ctypes cannot known that the object will no longer be accessed from C after this call).

Comment: @MarkTolonen In the actual code,  the create callback has extra parameters.  The C library calls it to indicate that a certain condition exists. When this condition no longer exists, it calls the destroy callback.  The C library doesn't need to known anything about the object.  It just keeps it around (as a void* pointer) until the condition no longer exists, so that it can notify the application. This technique is very efficient and at the same time keeps a complete separation between library and application, which is good.  It will work equally well for a C application using this library.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Describe how the callbacks are used more precisely in C and there is likely a better way to do it in Python.

Comment: You need to expose to us the lifecycle of the `Object` object. As I see it, you should keep a reference to the Python object at the Python level and destroy it at the *same time as you call destroy*. In general, memory allocated in Python should be freed in Python.